# Controller and model data store access ember.js

Tags: model, ember.js, controller

I'm currently using "ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js" to manage the persistence and data storage for my ember application.

user.js

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName:     DS.attr('string'),
    lastName:      DS.attr('string'),
    category:      DS.attr('string'),
    status:        DS.attr('string'),
    position:      DS.attr('string'),
    fullName:      function()
    {
       return '%@ %@'.fmt(this.get('firstName'), this.get('lastName'))
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.User.FIXTURES = 
[
 {
   id:          1,
   firstName:   'Derek',
   lastName:    "H",
   category:    "admin",
   status:      "offline",
   position:    "3232"
 },
 {
   id:          2,
   firstName:   'Jim',
   lastName:    "H",
   category:    "admin",
   status:      "online",
   position:    "322"
 }
];
```

UserListController.js

```
App.UserListController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    users: App.User.find()
});
```

store.js

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
```

From the above, I assumed that App.User.find() would return me all the users.  However, I get the following error:

Error From Firebug:

```
Your application does not have a 'Store' property defined. Attempts to call 'find' on model classes will fail. Please provide one as with 'YourAppName.Store = DS.Store.extend()'
TypeError: store is undefined
```

The message doesn't make sense, but the store is defined for App.  If the store was not defined, then the below code would not work.

In the below code, I call App.User.find() within the context of the route and it works.

router.js

```
Bib.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('index', { path: '/' });
});


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return ['a','b', 'c' ];
  },
  renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render();
        this.render('userList', { outlet: 'userList', into: 'application', controller: App.UserListController });//render the list in list outlet
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) 
  {
     controller.set('menu', model);
     controller.set('test', App.User.find());
  }
});
```

In the index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="userList" data-template-name="userList">
   {{#each controller}}
       {{firstName}}
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

I want the contoller there to represent the UserListController and have it have a reference to the User Model.  Keep in mind I can't hook this up in the route since I only have one route for this application.

I believe this is due to the context in which I'm making the call. In other words, using it within the Controller.I'm probably not understanding a fundamental concept how controllers and models are related.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
D

Comment: make sure you define your store **before** any call to `.find()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to make `find` calls within controllers. However, that isn't quite what is happening in `UserListController.js`.

You are calling `Ember.ArrayController.create` instead of `Ember.ArrayController.extend`. That is, you are creating a global instance of an `ArrayController` rather than defining a new class of controller.

At the time this `find` call is made, when `UserListController.js` is evaluated, the store you have defined has not yet been setup.

You can see this by removing this code and then evaluating it in your browser console once your app has started up.

However, creating a global controller and manually setting data on it is a pattern that is discouraged. The common pattern in Ember apps is to create controller classes which are instantiated and then populated with data by routes.

For example:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('user', { path: '/' });
});

App.UserIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});
```

This will automatically create a `UserIndexController` which is an `Ember.ArrayController` and set its `content` to `App.User.find()`.

Now, that is a simplified example and not what you are trying to do. It looks like you want to render a list of users, stored in a `UserListController`, into an outlet on your main template.

To do this you would need something like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  // you don't need to create an index resource
  // an IndexRoute is created by default
});

App.UserListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  },

  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('menu', model);
    this.controllerFor('userList').set('content', App.User.find());
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    var controller = this.controllerFor('userList');
    this.render();
    this.render('userList', {controller: controller});
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this still doesn't work.  You have the general idea of what i'm going for.  I basically want to pass in the userListController that has access to the User.find() model into the function that renders the template.  So within the template I can {{#each controller}} {{firstName}} {{/each}} for example.  I tested the code above and it doesn't recognize the controller.  I mean I can always go the route of looping through the userList that i defined in setupController, but that doesn't seem the right direction.

Comment: I've clarified my example of what i'm looking for.  It never loops to print out the data.

Comment: Oh, good catch, Justin, I completely missed the create vs extend thing that was going on there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably being caused by the `users: App.User.find()` line.  The call to `find()` is probably being called at the time that the model is first evaluated, which is probably before your store is defined.  The Ember Way (tm) is to use the route to set up the model for your controller.  Whatever is returned from the `model` method in your route will be set to the `'content'` property in your controller.

```
App.UserListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});

App.UserListController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  // you don't need anything here 
  // the model from the route will be set to 'content'
});
```

If you need the `'content'` property to be blank, and you need the list to live in the `'users'` property you could do this.

```
App.UserListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controller.set('content',[]);
    this.controller.set('users', App.User.find());
  }
});

App.UserListController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  // still don't need anything here
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the line that is causing the issue.  The problem is that I only have one route (the main route).  I wanted to have different rendering of templates with different controllers and isolate specific functionality to the controller itself vs. giving the scope to the main controller.